# Enable Wifi Randomization in Win10

Tags: windows-10, wifi-configuration

Windows settings doesn't allow me to enable randomization.

[image]

And if I click my wifi connection..

[image]

In order to investigate the `something is managed by my organization` I went to group policy and filtered all altered settings.. zero!
And since I'm not part of a domain.. this is weird but anyway.

My card seems to be supporting randomization (running `netsh wlan show wirelesscapabilities`)
[image]

Trying to enable it manually from an elevated command prompt displays error:
[image]

I am the Administrator, and sole user of this computer. No group policy.. So this has left me confused. Any suggestions?

```
System: Windows 10 Enterprise
Wifi adapter: Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless-AC 7265
```

Comment: If you use the built-in Administrator does anything change?

Comment: @Ramhound good idea but with exact the same behavior. Also note that it was the first time I used the built-in admin was to check your suggestion, so there is nothing manually configured for it.

Comment: Just to confirm, because the message tells me otherwise in every possible way, this computer is NOT connected to an active domain?

Comment: In my experience If you make changes using reg edits or powershell doing regedits you will get that notification. For example - Don't ask for feedback - "Set-ItemProperty -Path HKCU:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Siuf\Rules -Name NumberOfSIUFInPeriod -Type DWord -Value 0" . This will show up in the feedback settings as managed.

Comment: @Ramhound yes, **not part of a domain** just a local user